# ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution with golang

Tags: go, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i've created jenkins with pipeline to check go code analyze it with sonarqube but got error
when running this step on jenkins:

```
${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner \
                    -Dsonar.projectKey=go-crud \
                    -Dsonar.projectName=go-crud \
                    -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 \
                    -Dsonar.sources=. \
                    -Dsonar.sonar.exclusions=**/*_test.go,**/vendor/** \
                    -Dsonar.sonar.tests=. \
                    -Dsonar.sonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go \
                    -Dsonar.sonar.test.exclusions=**/vendor/** \
```

i got error:

```
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module go-crud
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=63ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 8.154s
INFO: Final Memory: 10M/39M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:291)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.completeScannerExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:77)
    at ....
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
```

please help, i really appreciate any response

Comment: mb version of sonar server is deprecated, mb you use 
incompatible version of java on the system. you havent provided much info 
ps https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/